# My CSS Stylesheet Isn't Linking

Tags: html, css, eclipse

So, I've been looking for solutions to this for over an hour. I've checked path issues. I've checked syntax. I can't find any inherent issues. I'm sure it's an issue with the "link" tag since an internal stylesheet works just peachy. I am using a dynamic web project with Eclipse if that helps.

Here is the stylesheet (master.css):

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
body{
    background-color: #000000;
    color: green;
}
```

And here is the the .xhtml file (main.xhtml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="master.css"/>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <div style="border-width: 2px; 
          border-color: blue; border-style: solid;">
         <ui:insert name="header">
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml" />
         </ui:insert>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div style="border-width: 2px; 
          border-color: green; border-style: solid;">
         <ui:insert name="content">
            <ui:include src="body.xhtml" />
         </ui:insert>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div style="border-width: 2px; 
          border-color: red; border-style: solid;">
         <ui:insert name="footer">
            <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" />
         </ui:insert>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

[Here is the Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyNrP.png)

I've also confirmed via the Windows File System that they are in the same directory.

Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: Does the console display a file not found error?

Comment: The only error I get is "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError," but that's probably just because I haven't added any java files yet. Thought the CSS was a bit quicker to do first.

Answer (score 0):

Since your CSS under the same parent as your `main.xhtml` file, try placing a forward-slash in your `href` attribute in your `<link>` tag. So:

```
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/master.css" />
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't work. I've even tried: ../WebContent/master.css and that doesn't work.

Comment: I'm really new at eclipse, so I don't know where that would be. I get a 404 error when navigating to http://localhost:8080/Swine/WebContent/master.css however.

Comment: What browser are you using? If you're using Chrome, open up the Developer Tools/Inspect Element and click Network while you're at the main.xhtml file.

Comment: The Network tab shows that it took about 50 milliseconds to download the css file. I can't see a 404 message there.

Comment: Now I'm seeing this error: GET http://localhost:8080/Swine/faces/master.css